Question regarding market makers and options contracts
I was reading up about market makers and how they provide liquidity and how you can "predict" their movements.I came across this paragraph when reading an article

"Volume Analysis: One of the primary indicators of market maker
activity is trading volume. An unusual spike in volume, particularly
in options markets, can often precede large moves in stock prices. For
instance, if a market maker is accumulating a significant position in
call options, it may signal their anticipation of an upward price
movement."

When they say that "there is an unusual spike in volume which precedes large moves in stock prices", I assume they meant that market makers know there will be large moves in a stock price in a certain direction. So as a result, they end up making trades on one side of the market ie buy side if they think the price will fall, in order to stop drastic price movements.
But how does this relate to the options market, if they are trying to stop drastic STOCK price movements, why load up on option positions?

Market Makers do not want to take a position in the market - they only providing liquidity by making trades when there are not enough active market participants to keep a market from stagnating.
They probably use options to hedge their position if they get too far on one side. For example, if they expect a lot of buyers and think they will need to sell to maintain liquidity, they may buy call options to reduce their "short" exposure (not "short" in the literal sense of borrowing stock, but short meaning they lose money if a stock goes up).
So an increase in call option volume could indicate that a market maker expects to have to sell a lot of stock because there are a lot of people buying it. Whether they are accurate in their predictions or whether it actually prevents rapid rises from an imbalance of demand is another question.

oh thank you so much this helped me a lot .

It's the other way around.  Market makers hedge their option positions primarily by buying and selling stock.  This is based on the delta of the option.
